# Editing config.xml file without being overwritten?

Tags: meteor

Basically my cordova app has an issue where the keyboard when shown throws off the entire layout of my app.. the fix is said to be adding the following code to the config.xml file:

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
```

Problem is when I do this and run Meteor run android-device the config.xml reverts to the previous version. How do I prevent his happening? The meteor guide was no help, it just says the following:
http://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#advanced-build

Comment: You cannot do this using `run android-device` but you can build the app for Android and edit the xml in the Android project dir and then build the app using Gradle (CLI or via AndroidStudio). Note that the XML will be overwritten on every Meteor project rebuild to the same directory.

Comment: @MasterAM well the Meteor guide says itself it's possible but with little information on how so I was hoping someone here knew step by step how to create a dummy plugin like the guide says

Comment: AFAIK, `cordova-build-override` is not in use anymore, and since I don't have experience with crating Cordova plugins, I too hope that someone would be able to help you with that. You can use the method I suggested to quickly test if the setting helps before creating a plugin for it.

Comment: @MasterAM I will do that, thanks for that :)

Comment: @LisaS Looks like it is still in use (at least in Meteor) according to this http://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#advanced-build. They don't recommend to use it often, but if you need you can do it.